# EF 4 + MVC: jQuery autocomplete and RemoteValidation conflict issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete, remote-validation

I have the known issue with jQuery autocomplete and Remote Validation: if I write some values inside an autocomplete control, when I select the value and the control lose focus, the value passed to remote validation is the typed one and not the selected one.

For example:

I type **LEO**, autocomplete shows me **LEO** N and **LEO** PARD and I select LEOPARD. The remote validation is triggered, **but the valued passed is the typed text LEO and NOT the selected one**.

I tried the [following solution](http://www.culbertsonexchange.com/wp/?p=190) described by Mr James on CulbertonExchange, but it needs to submit data to the form, **while I still need to trigger the validation immediately on selection or lost focus**:

```
     <!-- THE AUTO TRIGGER TO REMOTE VALIDATION IS DISABLED, BUT THIS IS NOT REQUIRED BEHAVIOUR -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var validatorSettings = $('#myform').validate().settings;
            validatorSettings.onkeyup = false;
            validatorSettings.onfocusout = false;
        }
     </script>
```

I also tried setting `selectFirst` and/or `autoFocus` to `true`, but it still does not work:

```
     $("#fieldtovalidate").autocomplete({
         selectFirst: true,
         autoFocus: false,
         ....
```

I think that I could solve my problem, disabling onkeyup and onfocusout events and re-enabling them everytime `onClose` event of the autocomplete occurs? What do you think about this possible solution. How could be implemented?

Thanks in advance for your precious help!